# Newer EaselJS version update breaks animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, easeljs, createjs

I have a working animation using BitmapAnimation, but with the newer version 0.7.0 this  class has been replaced with the Sprite class and is now depracated, I'm updating my code to the new class, but there seems to be problems with my animations.

On the old version the animations play whichever animation I request simply, by using for example:

```
playerAnimation[i].gotoAndPlay("idle");
```

But now they seem as if they are stuttering. As if repeating frames ridiculously quickly, or jumping back to frame one at each tick.

I'm thinking it may have something to do with the updated ticker in this version. The only changes to my code are these:

Before (BitmapAnimation and old Tick):

```
...
playerAnimation[i] = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(spriteSheet[i]);
...
createjs.Ticker.addListener(tick);
createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
...
function tick() {
...
}
```

After Changes (BitmapAnimation replaced by Sprite, and Tick function altered to new version):

```
...
function handleEvent(event) {
    if (event.type == "tick") {
        this.tick(event);
    }
}
...
playerAnimation[i] = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet[i]);
...
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', tick);
createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(60);
...
function tick(event){
...
}
```

These are literally the only changes that have been made to the code. I even copied and pasted all the other code across, except the necessary changes, to the new file in case I'd made any unintentional changes.

I know the Sprite class has added some new methods, so I wondered whether they've fiddled with the old way of doing things.

Any ideas? Need any more code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the problem!

With the new update of EaselJs they replaced the "frequency" attribute of SpiteSheet to a "speed" attribute. Therefore whereas before I used "4" as my "frequency"; which ran the animation 4x slower, now the under "speed", it runs the animation 4x faster!

Anyway thanks guys :)